# Where to put my framework classes using package-by-feature convention?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, package, naming-conventions

I've been reading a lot about package-by-feature naming convention. So I've decided to give it a try in a new project. However, I'm not sure how it should be named my packages that will be used by most of my classes, since I'm using a huge framework, such as `Spring` and `Hibernate`, for example.

This is how handle our `Spring contexts` classes:

[image]

And our `database` access class, the one that manages connections and so on.

[image]

I've a draft about this: using a common package for these frameworks, like:

```
com.company.project.common.spring
com.company.project.common.database
```

But I'm afraid that this still looks like `package-by-layer` a bit. :)
How the packages that will be accessed by my `feature classes` should be created ?

Comment: Not sure what your question really means, could you elaborate it a bit?

Comment: About conventions, if you use a framework to build your application, you should follow the framework guideline. That make the things easy to understand in the future. So just follow the *Spring* conventions here. That's just my opinion.

Comment: @MarioSantini I would like to know where to put my framework packages following the package-by-feature design.

Comment: @MarioSantini Also, regarding Spring convention, they follow the package-by-layer approach, which is not my purpose at the moment.
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html

Comment: As Spring follow a different convention, as you replied, you should think about my comment on stay with the framework convention. The only purpose of a convention is to organaise a project in a way that is easy to understand. If you have 2 different convention in your project than your purpose will lead you to a mure confusing situation. But this is just my opinion, I'm not sure about that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The common recommendation is "package by feature, not layer". What I often do is "package by feature, *then* layer". I also think that top-level packages should be "feature"-based (functional components, whatever). But I also like to have my layers separated into sub-packages.

From my point of view, framework-related code does not per se constitute "features" (as in "important, high-level aspects of the problem domain"), therefore package-by-feature is does not make much sense here. But still, this is important code and you need an approach to structure it.

I am normally use two approaches:

If I need to extend or augment libraries I'm using, I structure packages parallel to the package structure of the library. For instance if I'd need to implement some new number formatter for Spring, I'll probably name the package `com.acme.foo.springframework.format.number`, parallel to `org.springframework.format.number`.

However if I need to implement common base classes for layers of features, this would be probably something like `com.acme.foo.common.<layer>`. For instance if we have `com.acme.foo.<feature>.dataaccess` packages for data access layer of some feature, `com.acme.foo.common.dataaccess` could hold base classes for data access layers of all features.

Both approaches are used in parallel. You just have to decide whether some class is a framework or library extension (can you imagine using it outside this project?) or is it closer to the layers of your project.